# Inserting values into two BSTs sorted differently

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, binary-search-tree, function-pointers

For a project I'm working on in school I have to insert a pointer to one object into two BSTs. One BST is sorted by the APN(a unique key), and the other is sorted by price(non unique). We are using templates, so I asked my professor how to accomplish this and she said to use function pointers. When I tried to do so, I came across a few errors I don't know how to resolve.

The object is defined as

```
class House
{
    private:
    string APN; // Unique key
    int price;  // Non-unique key

    string address;
    int bedrooms;
    double bathrooms;
    int sqFt;
}
```

In main, after I've created the object I try to run.

```
uniqueTree->insert(newHouse, comparePrimaryKey);
nonUniqueTree->insert(newHouse, compareSecondaryKey);
```

Where each function is defined as

```
int comparePrimaryKey(const House* &left, const House* &right)
{
    if(left->getAPN() < right->getAPN())
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}

int compareSecondaryKey(const House* &left, const House* &right)
{
    if(left->getPrice() < right->getPrice())         // right > left
       return -1;
    else                                            // right < left
       return 1;
}
```

But I get an error saying

```
"Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'int (*)(House *const &, House *const &) 
with an lvalue of type 'int (const House *&, const House *&)'"
```

There is a BinaryNode object pointer called rootPtr in the Binary Tree file, and insert is defined as a purely virtual function.

```
BinaryNode<ItemType>* rootPtr;
virtual bool insert(const ItemType & newData, int compare(const 
ItemType&, const ItemType&)) = 0;
```

The binary node class:

```
template<class T>
class BinaryNode
{   
private:
    T              item;         // Data portion
    BinaryNode<T>* leftPtr;     // Pointer to left child
    BinaryNode<T>* rightPtr;        // Pointer to right child

public:
    // constructors
    BinaryNode(const T & anItem)    {item = anItem; leftPtr = 0; rightPtr = 0;}
    BinaryNode(const T & anItem, 
           BinaryNode<T>* left, 
           BinaryNode<T>* right) {item = anItem; leftPtr = left; rightPtr = right;}
    // mutators
    void setItem(const T & anItem) {item = anItem;}
    void setLeftPtr(BinaryNode<T>* left) {leftPtr = left;}
    void setRightPtr(BinaryNode<T>* right) {rightPtr = right;}
    // accessors
    T getItem() const    {return item;}
    BinaryNode<T>* getLeftPtr() const  {return leftPtr;}
    BinaryNode<T>* getRightPtr() const {return rightPtr;}

    bool isLeaf() const {return (leftPtr == 0 && rightPtr == 0);}
};
```

In the BST file, insert is defined as

```
template<class ItemType>
bool BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::insert(const ItemType &newEntry, int 
compare(const ItemType &, const ItemType &))
{
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNodePtr = new BinaryNode<ItemType>(newEntry);
    BinaryTree<ItemType>::rootPtr = _insert(BinaryTree<ItemType>::rootPtr, 
newNodePtr, compare(newNodePtr->getItem(), BinaryTree<ItemType>::rootPtr()->getItem()));
    return true;
}
```

I am also getting an error at the BinaryTree::rootPtr line saying that

```
Called object type 'BinaryNode<House *> *' is not a function or function pointer
```

Comment: try to change 
comparePrimaryKey(const House* &left, const House* &right)
to
comparePrimaryKey(const House* left, const House* right)

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple program that solve your first problem, i added the definitions of some function so that i can test your class and functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class House
{
    private:
    std::string APN; // Unique key
    int price;  // Non-unique key

    std::string address;
    int bedrooms;
    double bathrooms;
    int sqFt;

public:

    House(std::string apn, int prix)

    {
    APN = apn;
    price = prix;

    }
    std::string getAPN(void)

    {
    return APN;

    }


        int getPrice()
        {

        return price;

        }

};

    int comparePrimaryKey( House *const  &left,  House *const  &right)
{
    if(left->getAPN() < right->getAPN())
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}

int compareSecondaryKey( House *const  &left,  House *const  &right)
{
    if(left->getPrice() < right->getPrice())         // right > left
       return -1;
    else                                            // right < left
       return 1;
}

// Main function for the program
int main( )
{

    int PrimaryKey =0;
    int SecondaryKey=0;

    House right("droite",2050);
    House left("gauche",2000);



    PrimaryKey =  comparePrimaryKey(&left, &right);
    SecondaryKey =  compareSecondaryKey(&left, &right);

std::cout<< PrimaryKey << std::endl;
std::cout << SecondaryKey << std::endl;

    std::system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```